# changing size and position of color bar

Tags: colorbar

I want to change the size and position of my map colorbar. When I try to change the size and location of the colorbar, it is distorted in shape, I don't know why. Can anybody kindly help me. Please guide me why the set command distorts the clorbar? The location of the color bar should be 'southoutside'.The code is as under:

```
clear all,close all,clc
ax = worldmap('world');
load geoid
R = georasterref('RasterSize',[180 360],'Latlim',[-90 90],'Lonlim', [0 360]);
levels = [-70 -40 -20 -10 0 10 20 40 70];
geoshow(geoid, R, 'DisplayType', 'contour','LevelList',levels,'Fill','on','LineColor','black')
coast = load('coast.mat');
geoshow(coast.lat, coast.long, 'Color', 'white', 'LineWidth', 1.5)
cb = contourcbar('peer',ax,'Location','southoutside');
caxis([-110 90])
colormap(hsv)  
set(get(cb,'XLabel'),'String','Geoid Undulation in Meters')
a=get(cb); %gets properties of colorbar
a.Position %gets the positon and size of the color bar

set(cb,'Position',[0.10      0.20     0.80     0.08])% To change size and position
```